# Weave.blitz does not recognise exp function

Tags: optimization, scipy

I am trying to use weave but it keeps giving me a strange error.
It boils down to the following, when I run this simple test

```
from scipy import weave
from scipy import empty
import numpy as np
from numpy import *

b=np.ones((10))
c=np.ones((10))
expr = 'exp(b)'
a = empty( 10, 'd' ); weave.blitz(expr)
print a
```

I just get as an error

"NameError: name 'sin' is not defined"

The same if I use exp, log or any other function, and I have no idea why it would not recognise any of them. Same if I have instead a

```
from math import *
```

statement at the beginning, any idea why this is happening?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: Sorry, the error is actually

NameError: name 'exp' is not defined

 (I wrongly reported the result of a different test with trying to calculate sin, but the problem is actually the same

Comment: You should update your question with this information instead of having it as a comment.

Comment: It seems that trigonometric functions (as well as any other ufunc) are out of the scope of blitz. It is really just meant to be used with basic numpy array operations.